CiviCase, Manage Case not possible from other perspective than case client: DB Error: constraint violation (Bug in searchkit/form for case?)
On CiviCrm 5.75.1,
I can access a case from the contact that is the client in this case. e.g., I am going to the relations tab of that contact, choose the case and choose "manage case" from the menu.
This is also possible from a contact's site that has another role in that case. It is supposed to be the same case, accessed from to different perspectives. However, the URLs are different. More important, if I try to actually change anything about that case (e.g. the case's status), if I do this after i have accessed the case from any other contacts side than the client, the status will not be changed, instead i get a "DB Error constraint violation" message.
I believe the problem lies with the URL that the form/search provides, since the URLs are different. I also think the problem lies with the searchkit/formbuilder being in charge for providing the display of cases now.

Thank you. Yes, this https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2509
might very well be the problem here.

Thanks for posting this but it doesn't really answer the question. If you'd like to show your appreciation please upvote the answer from Demerit.

Yes this is a known issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2509
What you're describing is slightly different but I believe is the same underlying issue.
If someone wants to pick up trying to deal with it again there might be some pointers in that ticket.
